# SignalR with dynamic binded grid in kendo

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I want to use SignalR in kendoGrid but the problem is my grid is dynamically bind. That is the columns are coming dynamically, so I want to use SignalR to update the rows. For ex. "A" user can see "c1","c2","c3" columns in grid, "B" user can see "c2","c4","c5" Columns in grid. If "A" user update any row and make some changes in "c2" columns it should reflect for both users "A" and "B" using SignalR. Could anyone give some ides, how to achieve this in MVC kendoGrid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a trick here. Use a stored procedure and select all the columns on the basis of your condition. Now bind the model using this stored procedure. This means now your model has all the properties which is required. The model has all the columns but the visible logic will be according to the user's view, i.e. "A" user can see "c1","c2","c3" columns in grid, "B" user can see "c2","c4","c5" Columns in grid. Now if "A" user update any row and make some changes in "c2" columns, all the model will push to the SignalR function. The SignalR will push the whole model and all the properties but the columns will visible to him according to your visible logic.

Comment: let me check this. I think this is very good solution. Could you please help me to write visible logic?

Comment: @DangerousCoder lets do 1 thing, in your store procedure add one column which will contain the name or id of the visible columns. Then apply the visiblity check only on those columns. :)